# Is there a way to list out files and delete by creator in unix or linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have to list out the file and then i have to delete the file by the creator.

I have used below command to list the files :-
ls -lrt

but i am not sure how i can delete the file by the creator name.

please help me asap.

Comment: Maybe it's just a language point, but the `Owner` and the `Creator` are sometimes not the same thing. The responses you'll get (I think) will be the owner of the file, which may or may not be the creator.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a list of files, and which ones you want to delete and which ones you want to keep. Otherwise your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `find`. First find the right syntax and confirm the matches:

```
find /path/to -type f -user username -maxdepth 1
```

If all looks ok, you can go ahead and make it delete the matched files:

```
find /path/to -type f -user username -maxdepth 1 -delete
```

Of if your version of `find` doesn't have `-delete` then you can do like this:

```
find /path/to -type f -user username -maxdepth 1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: If the OP's find utility supports it there is a `-delete` option.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this

```
find /path/to/files -user username -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

This will recursively search everything under `/path/to/files` for files owned by `username`

Another option is to use the [deluser](http://man.he.net/man8/deluser) command and the `--remove-all-files` switch

```
deluser --remove-all-files username
```

Comment: The OP seems not very experienced. I wouldn't recommend him `rm -fr`, especially considering he's asking about deleting "files", no mention about directories.